# Collision Detection between a MovieClip on the timeline and one drawn in actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, collision-detection

I'm making a program that lets the user draw shapes on the screen with the mouse. When they're done they press a button to finish. The user is only allowed to draw on a certain area of the stage, to control this on the timeline i have a movie clip that takes up all the space the user isnt alowed to draw in.

When the user presses the button i want the programe to check that the shape the user drew isnt touching the moiveclip. I want it to do this without taking the border of the movieclip into account so i cant use hitTestObject()

heres what i have so far:

```
//------------------------------DRAW SHAPE------------------------------
    private var shape:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

    public function startDraw(e:MouseEvent):void {
        shape.graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
        shape.graphics.lineStyle(4, 0x000000, 0.8);

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, beginDraw);
    }

    public function beginDraw(e:MouseEvent):void {
        shape.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    }

    public function stopDraw(e:MouseEvent):void {
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, beginDraw);
    }
//--------------------------CHECK FOR COLLISION---------------------------
    public function bclick(e:MouseEvent):void {
        if(cd(mcOnTimeline, shape)){
            trace("HIT IT");
        }else{
            trace("DIDNT HIT");
        }
    }
    public function cd(mc1:MovieClip, mc2:MovieClip):Boolean{
        var mc1Bounds:Object = mc1.getBounds(mc1);
        var mc2Bounds:Object = mc2.getBounds(mc1);
        //return(mc1Bounds.intersects(mc2Bounds));

        var mc1BmpD = new BitmapData(mc1Bounds.width, mc1Bounds.height, true, 0);
        var mc2BmpD = new BitmapData(mc2Bounds.width, mc2Bounds.height, true, 0);
        //mc1BmpD.draw(mc1Bounds);
        //mc2BmpD.draw(mc2Bounds);
        //return(mc1BmpD.intersects(mc2BmpD));

        if(mc1BmpD.hitTest(new Point(mc1Bounds.x, mc1Bounds.y), 255, mc2BmpD, new Point(mc2Bounds.x, mc2Bounds.y),255)){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
```

The commented out stuff is different things ive tryed to get this working

Answer (score 1):

I would test while drawing; when the user is drawing (mouse button down) test if the mouse x,y is hitting the movieclip. If so, set a flag accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of your hitTest shape you might want to consider using BitmapData.hitTest(), which should be more efficient. Check out [Mike Chamber's blog post on the subject](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-bitmapdata-hittest-for-collision-detection/).

Comment: I am using it on this line

`mc1BmpD.hitTest`

Comment: Ah yes... so you are. Looking closer at your code you're not drawing anything to your BitmapDatas - you need to uncomment those draw()s, and pass in the MCs themselves instead of the 'mcXBounds' Rectangles. Also you said this twice: `getBounds(mc1);` which you may not have meant to do?